# How do you split a binary number into two halves, excluding one of the digits?

Tags: computer-science, binary

I have the number `110111001 (441)`. I want to extract three numbers from it:

```
110100000 (416)
000010000 (16)
000001001 (9)
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You have not specified how you want to split it.  If the number has an odd number of bits  with the central one being $1$, it appears you want the part before the central $1$, with the rest replaced by $0$s, the central $1$ with the trailing bits replaced by $0$s, and the final bits.  What if the central bit is $0$?  What if there are an even number?  Please ask a question that can be answered.

Comment: Sorry If I was unclear, I was asking how three specific numbers could be dirived from the original, not about how I could take any number and split it into three sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a bitwise implementation, note that

`416 = 441 & (0xf << 5)`

`16 = 441 & (1 << 4)`

and

`9 = 441 & (0xf << 0)`

can all be obtained by forming a 1 bitmask over continuous digits and shifting.

Comment: Why do you assume there are exactly $9$ bits?  OP didn't say that.  OP didn't say a lot of things about what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the number "modulo" some power of two, record that number, then subtract it. And then you can repeat this process.

As an example in base ten, consider the number $n := 46789$.

If I wanted to extract from this 46, 7, and 89, then I would operate as follows:

1. Compute $d:= n \mod 100$, which will be $89$.
2. Compute $m := (n-d)/100$, which will be $467$, and return this $\mod 10$, which will be $b := 7$.

3. Compute $(m - b)/10$, which will be $46$. Return this.

Here it is implemented in Desmos:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pni7mjpq4m